# The Heap size goes up even when there is no activity, according to GC logs

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a spring boot service, which is used to run some end to end automation tests on an ETL.
So there is activity only when the tests are running. If not there is nothing, and I expect the GC to go to work and clear out all heap.

But this doesn't happen.

My service is not the most efficient, but the test service doesn't have any variables which could hold heap of too long after the tests are done. I do have a dependency on the service under test, which might have some configurations which might Dominate and occupy some space, but that shouldn't be more than 400 MB.

But how do I make sure that the heap memory being used by my test service goes down after the tests are done and the service is sitting idle?

The service has these JVM args

```
                        -Xms1024m
                        -Xmx3500m
                        -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
                        -XX:+UseCompressedOops
                        -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
                        -XX:HeapDumpPath=logs/heapdump.bin
                        -XX:+PrintGCDetails
                        -Xloggc:logs/gc.log
                        -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary
                        -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError
                        -XX:ErrorFile=logs/crashDump.log
```

Its running on an instance with 1 core and 4 GB RAM.

These are the GC logs:

```
22419.450: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.456/1.456 secs] [Times: user=1.45 sys=0.00, real=1.46 secs]
22419.450: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
22419.455: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.005/0.005 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
22472.283: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22472.283: [ParNew: 145788K->17022K(153344K), 0.1940179 secs] 445267K->374202K(2429232K), 0.1941563 secs] [Times: user=0.38 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs]
22532.363: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22532.363: [ParNew: 153342K->17022K(153344K), 0.1939718 secs] 510522K->435660K(2429232K), 0.1940797 secs] [Times: user=0.38 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs]
22651.965: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22651.965: [ParNew: 153342K->17023K(153344K), 0.1861304 secs] 571980K->495243K(2429232K), 0.1862760 secs] [Times: user=0.36 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
22712.084: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22712.084: [ParNew: 153343K->17023K(153344K), 0.1794828 secs] 631563K->552861K(2429232K), 0.1796401 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
22772.194: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22772.194: [ParNew: 153343K->17022K(153344K), 0.1885376 secs] 689181K->615619K(2429232K), 0.1887093 secs] [Times: user=0.36 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
22832.288: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22832.288: [ParNew: 144659K->17022K(153344K), 0.2050234 secs] 743256K->673343K(2429232K), 0.2051719 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs]
22892.364: [GC (Allocation Failure) 22892.364: [ParNew: 153342K->17022K(153344K), 0.1991636 secs] 809663K->734706K(2429232K), 0.1993049 secs] [Times: user=0.38 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs]
23011.965: [GC (Allocation Failure) 23011.965: [ParNew: 153342K->17024K(153344K), 0.1910943 secs] 871026K->794353K(2429232K), 0.1912385 secs] [Times: user=0.37 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs]
```

Here you will see that the occupied heapSize is going up, without any activity being done. This shouldn't be happening right? Or is it caused by the GC?

This is what `top` tells me right now

```
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  4017056 total,   197456 free,  3276716 used,   542884 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   332476 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 15175 root      20   0 6295520 2.636g  13344 S   0.3 68.8  21:07.21 java
```

[image: This shows the Committed Heap vs Used Heap chart from New Relic]

Comment: There is no magic. If the heap grows and GC runs, the means the application is allocating. Even if there is no visible activity, something might be running on the background. Use profilers to find out what happens.

Comment: It's Spring Boot, tons of crap could be going on in the background

Comment: I am seeing that the committed heap never goes down even when the used heap seems to be down. How do we make sure that once the used heap is down, the committed heap is also released by JVM?

Comment: @DeepakGopal -  That's a different question.